# Are transporting and traveling with a dead body proscribed?

Tags: death, cremation

These days sometimes people need to take their loved ones to big cities for treatment unavailable in their place. Many a times the patient will die away from their home town. Then generally the relatives will take the dead body of the deceased in some vehicle to their home town for final cremation rites.

Is this kind of practise proscribed in the scripture?
I mean, I feel traveling with a dead body is something which is not very upright even if it was one's very close relative. For example, even Pandu was burnt in the forest and not taken to royal kingdom for creamation despite his larger kin being in Hastinapur.

So are scriptures anywhere against traveling and transporting the dead body from one place to another over a very long distance? Should not the cremation be done as soon as possible preferably in the nearest shamshan ghat rather then traveling? Like the important people required in the final rites be traveling to the city where the person died rather than bringing the dead body to their home city? I think traveling with a dead body in a vehicle (which in olden times would become an ox cart or horse cart) might be a bad idea. Is this thinking found in shashtr? Or my thinking is wrong?